# High traffic on certain questions

Tags: discussion

Just wondering: How come certain questions (example: [Do unique icon contours help people scan?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8040/do-unique-icon-contours-help-people-scan)) have +1k views when most questions have below 100?

Comment: Of note with such questions: when the question is long form, the question gets a lot of votes but the answers don't (as with this one). Looks like a "below the fold" issue. Also, there doesn't seem to be much conversion from interacting with this one question to further use of the site. I wonder if there are ways for us to promote further usage after seeing such high-traffic questions.

Comment: Yeah that'd be an interesting challenge. Can't think of a solution spontaneously though. Just guessing: It might also have something to do with where the traffic comes from; I imagine that a twitter user often looks at several links in quite a short time and the chance of real interest in the topic (and UX in general) is probably quite small.

Comment: True, but if there were more calls to action oriented towards such hit/run traffic perhaps more would stick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because people with a lot of followers, like [Jin, share the link to the question.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/56/publicist?userid=4)

Comment: And this must surely be a good thing for the site.